# QGIS Map Atlas Expression - How to refer to atlas_pagenumber in an expression for elevation symbology

Tags: qgis, expression, elevation, layouts, atlas

Can anyone point me to an example of how to refer to the current page number of QGIS Map Atlas layout within an expression for elevation symbology (which doesn't seem possible) or alternatively how to create a query to create a virtual layer of points that refers to the current atlas page number during map generation.

This is so I can display a different vector point in an elevation profile plot for each different page of 100+ pages generated by a map atlas.

Per the following screenshot's it is interesting it is possible to refer to an atlas page in a geometry marker expression using  @atlas_pagename for a symbology for a layer.

[image: Expression for a map layer symbol]

However frustratingly this functionality isn't available in the elevation symbols for the same layer.

[image: Expression for map layer elevation]

Its the elevation data that needs to be updated in the elevation plot so am not sure how do to this.

Any examples of suggestions greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you want is @*atlas_featurenumber*. It is accessible whenever the atlas is active.

The @*atlas_pagename* is the name generated by the *Page name* expression in the atlas-tab of the print-layout.

Note: A layout can contain pages that are not atlas-generated, so the feature-number is not always the same as the pagenumber in the layout.